# Programmatically move the pin in digdog MapKitDragAndDrop framework

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, mapkit

I have the [digdog MapKitDragAndDrop](https://github.com/digdog/MapKitDragAndDrop) in one my projects to achieve drag and drop pins. Im also allowing the user to search for location based on the address.

When the user searched and found his location coordinates, i want the pin to move to that location. Animation etc is not mandatory

I not able to figure out how to move the pin manually.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just provide a new set of coordinates for your annotation, remove it and put it back in the map view's annotations. Some code from you would help be precise.
But basically the idea is that you remove the annotation from the map view and then put it back again, with the good coordinates. As a DDAnnotation is a MKPlacemark, that shouldn't be too hard.

It would look like:

```
- (void)annotation:(DDAnnotation*)annotation hasNewCoordinates:(CLLocation)location{
   [_mapView removeAnnotation:annotation];
   annotation._coordinate = location;
   [_mapView addAnnotation: annotation];
}
```

Of course untested.